# iphone 4 & 5 dialer view: autolayout or code?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm developing a voip app for iOS and I don't know what is the best way to create the dialer interface (embedded in a tab controller) for iphone 4 and 5. 
I would like to know if I can structure  the layout via autolayout or is better to implement via code.

here is the image for the structure of the view either for iphone 4 and 5

[image]

Thanks in advice.
GP

**SOLVED:** 
I used autolayout defining a list of constraint, in particular i moved items like the number dialed label using >=,<= and equal constraints with different priorities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to implement via auto layout under storyboard/xib, it will save your lot of effort. This kind of task you can easily implement via auto-layout so go for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you give me some suggestion on how to implement via layout? An example of one or more constraint could be very helpful :)

Comment: Refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: i read the tutorial but i'm not able to obtain a good result.. for example i would like to fix the number buttons, call button and label size, putting numbers on the center, how should i do? thanks a lot!